# RichTextBox.RTF setter throwing System.ArgumentException. File format is not valid in Windows version 1803

Tags: windows, version, richtextbox, argumentexception

The following scenario is simulated to reproduce the crash:

1. Enable **Beta: unicode UTF-8 for world wide language support** (To
   enable Start=> Region & Language settings => Related settings ->
   Additional date, time & regional settings => Region -> Change date,
   time or number formats => select Administrative tab => Click on
   Change System Locale.
2. Check  Beta: unicode UTF-8 for world wide language support checkbox
3. Restart the system
4. In Windows forms Application => Add a form, RichTextBox, Button and
   a label OnButtonClick => add below lines

   ```
   richTextBox1.SelectAll();
   richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.SelectedRtf; //Leads Crash System.ArgumentException: File format is not valid.
   label1.Text = "RichTextBox1.Rtf = " + richTextBox1.Rtf;
   ```
5. If we UnCheck  **Beta: unicode UTF-8 for world wide language
   support**, and restart the system there was no issue.

Issue is observed with windows version 1803

Any help on this use case is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue from microsoft build 1803 and 1809 as well.
Work around solution can be found here.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/544623/issue-caused-by-unicode-utf-8-for-world-wide-langu.html

Comment: What is the work-around? I can't see any on the page your linked.